# Saving an Cell value to a variable in a for each loop VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In essence i'm trying to save a cell value to a variable but it keeps fiving runtime error 1004 .. no ideea what it means
I even tried saving i.row and i.column to some other values and then trying to run with them but still nothing

```
Sub ffs()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim value As Range
    Dim rowvalue As Integer
    Dim columnvalue As Integer
    Set Rng = Range("C2:AD61")
        For Each i In Rng
            rowvalue = i.Row
            columnvalue = i.Column
            value = i.Offset(-3, 0)
                Debug.Print value
        Next i
End Sub
```

Any ideeas?

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: value = i.Offset(-3, 0)

Comment: Yes, when i is C2, there is no cell 3 rows up.  It would be C-1 and there is no row 0 or -1.

Comment: :| what can i say... i completely forgot about the range i gave it xD... TYVM

Comment: @ScottCraner is absolutely right, plus - what is the reason to include rowvalue and columnvalue vars in the loop (you are not using these vars)?

Comment: @AlexBell they were just attempts made by the OP to find the error.

Comment: @ScottCraner OK, I got it. Looks like the issue is resolved. You should get a credit :). Rgds,

Comment: I see this as a typo not a true issue.  so I will let my comment stand. @AlexBell